# Stack at best SQL query child properties (parent id, not nested set)

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

First table (about about 100k records and growing):

```
idnod, idparentnod, idparam
```

Second table (about 2m records and growing):

```
idparam, idpropertie, idpropertievalue
```

I'm searching for the best way to get list of idpropertievalue's from a list of idnod=>idparam. A list of idnod=>idparam always starts from the parentest id list and can have up to five top level nods. They can generate about 50k low level children. Current maximum depth of tree is 4. Tables has btree innodb indexes.

My solutions has 4 inner joins in subqueries, using temp tables and it's execution time going to 1s. Too slow.

Any ideas?

My solution:

1. Fetch all rows from second table with matching idparam
2. Check result. If it's empty, then make up to 4 subselect like this:

   $selectEnumTree = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                                       ->from(array('ft' => 'firstTable'),
   array('idnod','idparam'))
                                       ->joinInner(array('et' => $selectEnumTree),'(p et.idnod=ps.idparentnod)', null);
3. Union all $selectEnumTree queries with group by (not distinct) idpropertievalue to remove duplicates and to get total list of idpropertie => idpropertievalue
4. Inner join second table with sql request from 3rd point

In my case only 4th generation can obtain properties. That is way I'm checking whether there is some at 1st step. If this wasn't true, it's okay to union results of 1st and 4th step. But the speed of this solution very frustrating

Comment: I think you should post your solution

Comment: Vercelli, my solution is very custom and I thought it wouldn't be interesting for public. Possibly it can even brake some logic in discussion. Here is my solution (topic update)

Comment: With the information you have given, I think it's hard to imagine what you are looking for. Posting actual data, expected results and what you've achieved so far is always helpful.http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056